# Java assign column in Observable list to @fxml column

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I am looking for advice as I cant make my form and underlaying `TableView` designed in scene builder display data from observable list. I am having model which is returning `ObservableList<ObservableList>`, which I want to assign to columns (for instance, `id`) in Controller of my form. Here is my code:

```
@FXML
private TableColumn id;


Database database = new Database();    
TableView tableView = new TableView();    
tableView.setItems(database.returnData()); // --> this is the method returning Observablelist     
id = tableView.getColumns().get(0); // --> line with error
```

and I am getting error

```
Error:(35, 44) java: incompatible types: java.lang.Object cannot be converted to javafx.scene.control.TableColumn
```

Can you please help me to get it working?
Thank you very much!

EDIT:
Would it be easier if I pull TableView instead of observable list from the database, initiate it in Controller and then assign @FXML columns to columns in pulled tableview? If yes, any idea how to do it? Thx for any help or word you might share. Peter

Comment: If your `TableColumn` is already defined in the FXML file, why do you need to reassign it in the Java code?

Comment: Hello James, I am just starting with java so maybe I am doing something wrong. What I am trying to achieve is to display columns I pulled out of the database in ObservableList into appropriate column in the form. Thus, I though I have to define @FXML column (id in my case) and assign (or bind?) values into it through code above. However, I had no luck. If you can share a word or advise, it would be fantastic. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to link your table and columns to your FXML definitions, but also create an `ObservableList` which you put into your table.

```
@FXML private TableView<SimpleFileProperty> table;
@FXML private TableColumn<SimpleFileProperty, String> sizeCol;
final private ObservableList<SimpleFileProperty> tableData =
                                        FXCollections.observableArrayList();
// ...
table.setItems(tableData);
```

Comment: Thank you for your time SnakeDoc, however its not changing the problem as its not solving my issue with assigning values to column in TableView on form or maybe I missed something?

Answer (score 0):

OK, just to closed this one. My problem was with return of ObservableList< ObservableList >, after change to ObservableList< myClass > it started to work. I strongly recommend below mentioned tutorial:

http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/table-view.htm